# Conditional replacement of values in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to understand how to conditional replace values in a dataframe without using a loop. My data frame is structured as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(11.77, 10.9, 10.32, 10.96, 9.906, 10.7, 11.43, 11.41, 10.48512, 11.19),
  b = c(2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0),
  est = numeric(10)
)
df
          a b est
1  11.77000 2   0
2  10.90000 3   0
3  10.32000 2   0
4  10.96000 0   0
5   9.90600 0   0
6  10.70000 0   0
7  11.43000 1   0
8  11.41000 2   0
9  10.48512 4   0
10 11.19000 0   0
```

What I want to do, is to check the value of `b`. If `b` is 0, I want to set `est` to a value from `a`. I understand that `df$est[df$b == 0] <- 23` will set all values of `est` to 23, when `b==0`. What I don't understand is how to set `est` to a value of `a` when that condition is true. For example:

```
df$est[df$b == 0] <- (df$a - 5)/2.533
```

gives the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In df$est[df$b == 0] <- (df$a - 5)/2.533 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Is there a way that I can pass the relevant cell, rather than vector?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Since you are conditionally indexing `df$est`, you also need to conditionally index the replacement vector `df$a`:

```
index <- df$b == 0
df$est[index] <- (df$a[index] - 5)/2.533
```

Of course, the variable `index` is just temporary, and I use it to make the code a bit more readible.  You can write it in one step:

```
df$est[df$b == 0] <- (df$a[df$b == 0] - 5)/2.533
```

For even better readibility, you can use `within`:

```
df <- within(df, est[b==0] <- (a[b==0]-5)/2.533)
```

The results, regardless of which method you choose:

```
df
          a b      est
1  11.77000 2 0.000000
2  10.90000 3 0.000000
3  10.32000 2 0.000000
4  10.96000 0 2.352941
5   9.90600 0 1.936834
6  10.70000 0 2.250296
7  11.43000 1 0.000000
8  11.41000 2 0.000000
9  10.48512 4 0.000000
10 11.19000 0 2.443743
```

---

As others have pointed out, an alternative solution in your example is to use `ifelse`.

Answer (score 28):

Try [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/)'s `:=` operator :

```
DT = as.data.table(df)
DT[b==0, est := (a-5)/2.533]
```

It's fast and short. See these linked questions for more information on `:=` :

[Why has data.table defined `:=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033106/why-has-data-table-defined-rather-than-overloading)

[When should I use the `:=` operator in `data.table`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029944/when-should-i-use-the-operator-in-data-table)

[How do you remove columns from a `data.frame`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072159/how-do-you-remove-columns-from-a-data-frame/7077154#7077154)

[R self reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768686/r-self-reference/7769727#7769727)

Comment: Beautiful , Thanks for references +1 for everything.

Comment: Very useful response.  If you use this, make sure to note that DT is not a function in the data.table package, but a reference for the data table object.

Answer (score 22):

Here is one approach. `ifelse` is vectorized and it checks all rows for zero values of `b` and replaces `est` with `(a - 5)/2.53` if that is the case.

```
df <- transform(df, est = ifelse(b == 0, (a - 5)/2.53, est))
```

Answer (score 11):

Another option would be to use [case_when](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.5/topics/case_when)

```
require(dplyr)

mutate(df, est = case_when(
    b == 0 ~ (a - 5)/2.53, 
    TRUE   ~ est 
))
```

This solution becomes even more handy if more than 2 cases need to be distinguished, as it allows to avoid nested `if_else` constructs.

Answer (score 7):

The  [R-inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), or the basic R-documentation will explain why using df$* is not the best approach here. From the help page for "[" :

"Indexing by [ is similar to atomic vectors and selects a list of the specified element(s).
Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]. Also, the partial matching behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument. "

I recommend using the `[row,col]` notation instead.  Example:

```
Rgames: foo   
         x    y z  
   [1,] 1e+00 1 0  
   [2,] 2e+00 2 0  
   [3,] 3e+00 1 0  
   [4,] 4e+00 2 0  
   [5,] 5e+00 1 0  
   [6,] 6e+00 2 0  
   [7,] 7e+00 1 0  
   [8,] 8e+00 2 0  
   [9,] 9e+00 1 0  
   [10,] 1e+01 2 0  
Rgames: foo<-as.data.frame(foo)

Rgames: foo[foo$y==2,3]<-foo[foo$y==2,1]
Rgames: foo
       x y     z
1  1e+00 1 0e+00
2  2e+00 2 2e+00
3  3e+00 1 0e+00
4  4e+00 2 4e+00
5  5e+00 1 0e+00
6  6e+00 2 6e+00
7  7e+00 1 0e+00
8  8e+00 2 8e+00
9  9e+00 1 0e+00
10 1e+01 2 1e+01
```

Comment: This deserves an upvote if you first add either a link to the R-Inferno page, or summarize the issues with `$` (or ideally both).

Comment: +1 Although I think the `$` operator is perfectly fine in this case.  (Also, I note that despite your warning you use `$` yourself...)

Comment: @Andrie: yes, I used it where it works (not that that is a lot of help :-) ).  The OP tried to use it to define what elements were being acted on, which is where the trouble started.  I just used it to define a condition that selected dataframe elements.  But you knew that :-)