# Conditionally change column value based on value in another column

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements

I have a dataset in R that is structured like so:

```
> head(top10_master, n = 5)
   sensitivity      PRODUCT NewRevenue NewQuantity NewProfit Change_Price Rev_Change Prof_Change Quant_Change Revenue Quantity  Profit
1:           1 PRODUCT33411    7067750    11809634   5790148      0.80000  1.2282115    1.173265    1.5591315 5754505  7574495 4935074
2:           1 PRODUCT35481    4484178     5721789   3278738      1.04978  1.0000000    1.000000    1.0000000 4484178  5721789 3278738
3:           1 PRODUCT26835    5239519     2239783   3950871      0.90000  1.1801825    1.125136    1.3884444 4439584  1613160 3511460
4:           1 PRODUCT33203    5872765     1139270   3125781      0.90000  1.3477930    1.161484    1.6487265 4357320   691000 2691195
5:           1 PRODUCT22426    4125707     1121494   3249458      0.80000  0.9590297    1.378040    0.4507613 4301960  2488000 2358029
```

I am trying to edit the `Change_Price` column to 1 (inside of a function) in the instances where the `Rev_Change and Quant_Change columns == 1`. I have tried every method I could find including using `dplyr` but for some reason none of these methods are working and the output is always the same. Please help.

I have tried too many methods to list them all but among them are all of the methods listed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214303/conditional-replacement-of-values-in-a-data-frame). For some reason, none of these methods is working.

Comment: Perhaps it is a case of floating point accuracy

Comment: @akrun I suspect you may be right because it seems like traditional subsetting is not recognizing `Change_Rev = 1` etc... how would I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As akrun suggested, maybe there is a [floating point accuracy issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/8099834). You could try using dplyr's [`near`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/near):

> This is a safe way of comparing if two vectors of floating point numbers are (pairwise) equal. This is safer than using ==, because it has a built in tolerance.

This might work for you:

```
library(dplyr)
top10_master$Change_Price[which(near(top10_master$Rev_Change, 1) & near(top10_master$Quant_Change, 1))] <- 1
```

Comment: the only problem with this solution is that it also seems to round the other values as well

Comment: @zsad512 I don't fully understand your issue. Can you post an example?

Answer (score -1):

```
top10_master$Change_Price[sapply(top10_master$Rev_Change, all.equal, 1) & sapply(top10_master$Quant_Change, all.equal, 1)] <- 1
```

Subset to the data you want to change and then assign.

Comment: as mentioned in my post @troh I have tried this and it didnt work

Comment: @zsad512 I've updated my answer from the comment above.

Comment: `Error in sapply(inData$Change_Rev, all.equal, 1) & sapply(inData$Change_Quant,  : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`

Comment: I checked the input data tables as well before posting ^ and they are all listed as `numeric` so not really sure whats going on here...

Comment: I'm assuming you used: `is.numeric(inData$Change_Rev); is.numeric(inData$Change_Quant)`