# Conditional replacement of values in entire dataframe

Tags: r

What's the appropriate way to replace values within an entire data frame, without specifying rows or columns?

Let's assume that I'd like to replace all values where `abs(x) > .5` by `<- "duck"`

In this case

```
> df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5), c = rnorm(5))
> df
            a          b          c
1  1.37481216 -0.1760366 -0.5122730
2  0.09204844 -0.4270991  0.3211998
3 -0.43563818  0.7560178  0.5399643
4 -0.02078887  0.5961020 -0.5985515
5  0.99129234 -0.9959395 -0.6488177
```

the desired output would be

```
            a          b          c
1  "duck"     -0.1760366  "duck"
2  0.09204844 -0.4270991  0.3211998
3 -0.43563818  "duck"     "duck"
4 -0.02078887  "duck"     "duck"
5  "duck"      "duck"     "duck"
```

While [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214303/conditional-replacement-of-values-in-a-data-frame) requires a specification of columns, I'm looking for a dynamic replacement for the entire data frame.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R

```
df[abs(df) > 0.5] <- "duck"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `replace`:

```
replace(df,abs(df)>0.5,"duck")
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(ifelse(abs(.) > .5, "duck", .)))
```