# Why is my conditional function changing all values to "FALSE" and how can I make it work?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am working on mutational data of genes which consists of one column per gene, with the gene either having "no alteration", or a specific mutation. In one column, I want the non-altered genes to be changed to "Wildtype", and all the different mutations to be changed to simply "Mutated". I have tried using the conditional function for this with the following code:

`dat$RB <- ifelse(dat$RB != "no alteration", dat$RB == "Mutated RB", dat$RB == "Wildtype RB")`

However, when I use this, all values in the column simply change to "FALSE". Why is this not working, and what should I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional replacement of values in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214303/conditional-replacement-of-values-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `case_when` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    mutate(RB = case_when(RB == 'no alteration' ~ 'Wildtype RB', TRUE ~ 'Mutated RB'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
dat$RB <- ifelse(dat$RB == "no alteration", "Wildtype RB", "Mutated RB")
```

Or without `ifelse` :

```
dat$RB <- c("Mutated RB", "Wildtype RB")[(dat$RB == "no alteration") + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question you ask for a solution--see @Ronak's. You also ask for a reason why your code isn't working. Here's an aswer to that.

The syntax of `ifelse` is threefold: the first argument specifies a condition; the second argument specifies what to do if the conditon holds true, and the third argument specifies what to do if the condition is not met. So if you put `ifelse(dat$RB != "no alteration", dat$RB == "Mutated RB", dat$RB == "Wildtype RB")` you are making two mistakes: first, you negate the condition that you actually want to match, namely that cells have the value `no alternation`; to mend that mistake you would need to replace `!=` by `==`. Second, I guess `dat$RB`is a **new** column; being new and as the `ifelse` command is being executed not yet extant, you cannot reference the column in the call to `ifelse`. To mend that mistake you need to specify the values themselves (without reference to the column), namely "Wildcard RB" and "Mutated RB".

Hope this clarifies the issue.