# Conditional replacement of values in a dataframe (by values at other places)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data frame` like *MyData* below:

```
country <- c("Gr","Gr","Gr","It","It","Eg","Eg","Li")
continent <- c("Eu",NA,NA,"Eu",NA,"Af",NA,"Af")
SomeData <- c(3,1,5,6,2,8,2,9)
MyData <- data.frame(Country=country, Continent=continent, Data=SomeData)
```

As you can see, the continent of Greece is Europe in some places, but is `NA` in most of the places. The same with Egypt and other countries of the real data frame. **I want to replace the `NA`s with the name of the country's continent, as it is named in the data frame** (Eu, Af, etc).

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

PS1: I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214303/conditional-replacement-of-values-in-a-data-frame) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824173/replace-a-value-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-conditional-if-statement?rq=1). None of them answers my question.
PS2: I have too many countries' names to manage.

Comment: `MyData %>% group_by(Country) %>% fill(Continent)` using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

Comment: @RonakShah, your answer works fine, but at the real dataframe I add `%>%   fill(Continent, .direction = "up")`. Thanks  lot!