# Subset data frame based on character vector of column names

Tags: r

Rookie question - thanks in advance for patience...

I have a dataframe:

```
vals <- c(1,1,1,1)
testdf <- data.frame("var1"=vals, "var2"=vals, "var3"=vals)
```

I have a character vector of variable names:

```
varnames <- c("var1", "var2")
```

This is a character vector b/c I use it to generate a formula earlier in the script.

I'd like to subset a dataframe such that variables in varnames are excluded, e.g.

```
newDF <- subset(df, select=-varnames)
```

This creates an error since `subset` expects names instead of characters. So, I use `lapply` to change the characters to names:

```
varnames <- lapply(varnames, as.name)
```

The result of this lapply function is a named(?) and nested(?) list.

```
[[1]]
var1

[[2]]
var2

[[3]]
var3
```

Here's where I get lost (I feel like Mugatu on crazy pills... is this confusing to anyone else!?). I can see that each value has correctly been changed from character to name, but it's in this weird nested structure - so when I try to subset, I get an error.

I've tried various solutions to unnest and unname, but with no success. This must be something easy I'm missing.

As a bonus - can someone tell me why it is ever useful for lapply to return this nested named list instead of simple vector? It seems very different than, for instance, Python. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7072159/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6286313/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define the names of the columns you want inside `[` (see the help file `?Extract` or `help("[")` for the subset operator `[`).

```
testdf[ names(testdf)[!names(testdf) %in% varnames] ]
## or
## testdf[, names(testdf)[!names(testdf) %in% varnames] , drop = FALSE]
```

Or, more concisely (thanks @Frank)

```
testdf[ setdiff(names(testdf), varnames)]
  var3
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
```

---

where

```
names(testdf)
# [1] "var1" "var2" "var3"
varnames
# [1] "var1" "var2"
```

And So

```
names(testdf) %in% varnames
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

And therefore

```
names(testdf)[!names(testdf) %in% varnames]
# [1] "var3"
```

Which is the same as

```
testdf[, "var3" ]
```

And `drop = FALSE` to stop it 'dropping' to a vector if there's only one column returned.

---

Also, if you look at the help file for `lapply(X, FUN, ...)`

```
?lapply
```

> lapply returns a list of the same length as X

This is why you're getting a list.

---

> As a bonus - can someone tell me why it is ever useful for lapply to return this nested named list instead of simple vector? It seems very different than, for instance, Python. Thank you.

When you're working with a list, and you want it to remain as a list.

Comment: Fyi, `x[!(x %in% y)]` is `setdiff(x,y)`

Comment: Excellent! Works great. Thanks Symbolix and @Frank

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `match` which returns an index

```
testdf[-match(varnames,names(testdf))]


#   var3
#1    1
#2    1
#3    1
#4    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements using `varnames[[1]]` etc. and convert it into a vector, if it makes it easier for you.

Source: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family

`lapply` takes a list and applies the function to every element of the list. The list can also have another list as an element. So it takes that into consideration and returns that nested structure.

Comment: A better source would be `help("[[")`. Generally, links are not preferred on this site, since they may eventually break.

Comment: Hi. I am relatively new here. I didn't get you. What should I use instead of the link?

Comment: Ohh you meant to suggest using help function in R. Got it :)