# R `which` function performance

Tags: r, performance

Working with some big data.frames in R, and wanted to know which one of the 2 options is more efficient timewise.

```
df[which(condition), ] = value
```

or

```
df[condition, ] = value
```

Assuming that most of the data doesn't fulfill the condition, and `length(which(condition))` is much much smaller than the boolean vector.

Is it more efficient to ask for specific indices than going through the whole data.frame/vector and for each row/element and choose it if the boolean vector is true at the position.

Or maybe if I call another function, it only delays performance.

I assumed someone else already asked this, but could not find an answer, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918657/whats-the-use-of-which) seems relevent, but the discussions I saw there are only if you need the boolean vector/indices again.

Comment: why don't you just run a benchmark with some of your real data? Look at `microbenchmark` package for example

Comment: The [NEWS file](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2016/000602.html) from R 3.3.0 says: "Thanks to a patch from Tomas Kalibera, x[x != 0] is now typically faster than x[which(x != 0)] (in the case where x has no NAs, the two are equivalent)."

Comment: @docendodiscimus, in my experience, checking like this is not very informative, sometimes I run exactly the same command and the time it takes is very different. 
I tried to check with `system.time()`, is `microbenchmark` more accurate?

Comment: Thanks! @Roland do you have any idea if the fact that most of the boolean vector is FALSE has any effect?

Comment: @T.G., yes, `microbenchmark` is more accurate because it runs the benchmark multiple times (100 times by default) and reports a summary

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: I don't think that the comparative efficiency between the two alternatives makes a big difference since, here, your main overhead comes from `"[<-.data.frame"` which accepts its "i" argument (the "condition" in your example) and uses it to subset the sequence of rows of the "data.frame" (search for `iseq <- seq_len(nrows)[i]` inside its body). So, I guess the question is (1) what is the difference in subsetting an integer vector with a logical (of same length) or an integer of indices and (2) how much does affect the overall `"[<-.data.frame"` call.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative implementation to `which()` that allocates the minimum space required.

```r
library(cpp11)
#> Warning: package 'cpp11' was built under R version 4.3.2

cpp11::cpp_function("SEXP cpp_which(SEXP x, bool invert = false) {
  R_xlen_t n = Rf_xlength(x);
  int *p_x = LOGICAL(x);
  bool is_long = n > R_SHORT_LEN_MAX;
  if (invert){
    if (is_long){
      R_xlen_t size = 0;
      for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) size += (p_x[j] == TRUE);
      R_xlen_t out_size = n - size;
      SEXP out = Rf_protect(Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, out_size));
      double *p_out = REAL(out);
      R_xlen_t whichi = 0;
      R_xlen_t i = 0;
      while (whichi < out_size){
        p_out[whichi] = i + 1;
        whichi += !(p_x[i] == TRUE);
        ++i;
      }
      Rf_unprotect(1);
      return out;
    } else {
      int size = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) size += (p_x[j] == TRUE);
      int out_size = n - size;
      SEXP out = Rf_protect(Rf_allocVector(INTSXP, out_size));
      int *p_out = INTEGER(out);
      int whichi = 0;
      int i = 0;
      while (whichi < out_size){
        p_out[whichi] = i + 1;
        whichi += !(p_x[i] == TRUE);
        ++i;
      }
      Rf_unprotect(1);
      return out;
    }
  } else {
    if (is_long){
      R_xlen_t size = 0;
      for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) size += (p_x[j] == TRUE);
      SEXP out = Rf_protect(Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, size));
      double *p_out = REAL(out);
      R_xlen_t whichi = 0;
      R_xlen_t i = 0;
      while (whichi < size){
        p_out[whichi] = i + 1;
        whichi += (p_x[i] == TRUE);
        ++i;
      }
      Rf_unprotect(1);
      return out;
    } else {
      int size = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) size += (p_x[j] == TRUE);
      SEXP out = Rf_protect(Rf_allocVector(INTSXP, size));
      int *p_out = INTEGER(out);
      int whichi = 0;
      int i = 0;
      while (whichi < size){
        p_out[whichi] = i + 1;
        whichi += (p_x[i] == TRUE);
        ++i;
      }
      Rf_unprotect(1);
      return out;
    }
  }
}")

x <- TRUE
y <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10^3, TRUE)
z <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10^7, TRUE)
z[sample.int(10^7, 10^6)] <- NA

a <- c(TRUE, rep_len(FALSE, 10^6))
b <- c(FALSE, rep_len(TRUE, 10^6))

library(bench)

mark(which(x), cpp_which(x, F))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 which(x)           1.2µs    1.3µs   698998.        0B        0
#> 2 cpp_which(x, F)    800ns    1.3µs   667628.        0B        0
mark(which(y), cpp_which(y, F))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 which(y)             2µs    2.4µs   220167.    5.91KB     22.0
#> 2 cpp_which(y, F)    2.3µs    2.5µs   251464.    1.95KB      0
mark(which(z), cpp_which(z, F))
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 which(z)          52.7ms   56.5ms      16.7    55.3MB    16.7 
#> 2 cpp_which(z, F)     18ms   22.1ms      40.6    17.2MB     9.66
mark(which(a), cpp_which(a, F))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 which(a)           833µs   1.02ms      952.    3.81MB     47.9
#> 2 cpp_which(a, F)    744µs 835.65µs     1111.        0B      0
mark(which(b), cpp_which(b, F))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 which(b)          2.04ms   2.94ms      323.    7.63MB     40.3
#> 2 cpp_which(b, F)   1.76ms   2.09ms      415.    3.81MB     25.6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>