# Loops and Conditional Statements

Tags: r

Using loop and conditional statements, I would like to identify rows that have a value over 2.50

```
customer <- c("john", "amy", "doug")
product  <- c("coffee", "pastry", "pastry")
store    <- c("a", "b", "c")
cost     <- c(5.50, 2.45, 3.00)

df <- data.frame(customer, product, store, cost)
```

I would like to identify purchases over $2.50 and save "store" and "product" as separate vectors associated with those purchases over $2.50.

So far, this is my code and it is not working...

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
    customer <- df[row, "customer"]
    product  <- df[row, "product"]
    store <- df[row, "store"]
    cost <- df[row, "cost"]

    if(cost > 2.50) {
        print(paste(customer, "purchased", product, "at", store, "for", cost))
    } 
}
```

This is not for working, and how do I save the two "product" and "store" as separate vectors?

Comment: Why do you need to save them?

Answer (score 0):

**There is no need for an explicit for loop.**

This saves columns `store` and `product` separately, for which `cost > 2.5`:

```
store.sel <- df[which(df$cost > 2.5), "store"]
product.sel <- df[which(df$cost > 2.5), "product"]
```

Or subset the `dataframe`

```
subset(df, cost > 2.5)
```

and then select the required columns

```
with(subset(df, cost > 2.5), paste(customer, "purchased", product, "at", store, "for", cost))
```

Comment: You don't need to use `which` : `df[df$cost > 2.5, "store"]` gives same result as `df[which(df$cost > 2.5), "store"]`

Comment: True. But it doesn't hurt either. In my opinion, returning indices has advantages for more complex filtering, and I consider it good (better) practice. See e.g. the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918657/whats-the-use-of-which).

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following which outputs a vector of your strings of interest:

```
df2 <- df[df$cost > 2.5,]
with(df2, paste(customer, "purchased", product, "at", store, "for", cost))

## [1] "john purchased coffee at a for 5.5" "doug purchased pastry at c for 3"
```

Comment: Thank you. This works! 

Is this feasible with a for loop and if conditional statement?

Comment: Yes, but often such operations are more efficient and more readable when not using a `for` loop. For future needs, you may want to look at `dplyr` (actually `tidyverse`) and / or `data.table`; these are quite efficient and avoid the need for most `for` loops.  These weren't necessary for this question though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are saving, but you could do something like this.

```
   df <- df[df$cost > 2.50,]
   cat(paste0(df$customer, " purchased ", df$product, 
       " at ",df$store, " for ", cost, "./n"))
```