# Error while finding the outliers for diamonds dataset

Tags: r

for the below code, i am getting an error:

```r
boxplot(diamonds$carat, diamonds$cut, diamonds$depth, diamonds$table, diamonds$x,
        diamonds$y, diamonds$z)
boxplot(diamonds$carat, diamonds$cut, diamonds$depth, diamonds$table, diamonds$x, 
        diamonds$y, diamonds$z)$out
outliers <- boxplot(diamonds$carat, diamonds$cut, diamonds$depth, diamonds$table, diamonds$x, 
                    diamonds$y, diamonds$z, plot = FALSE)$out diamonds[which(diamonds$carat, diamonds$cut, diamonds$depth, diamonds$table, diamonds$x, diamonds$y, diamonds$z %in% outliers),]
Newdata <- diamonds[-which(diamonds$carat, diamonds$cut, diamonds$depth, diamonds$table,
                           diamonds$x, diamonds$y, diamonds$z %in% outliers),]
```

error is

> Error in which(diamonds$carat, diamonds$depth, diamonds$table, diamonds$x,  : 
>     unused arguments (diamonds$x, diamonds$y, diamonds$z %in% outliers)

Comment: `which` returns column indices and you're subsetting rows. Also it's unclear what is contained in `outliers`. Too many arguments. Could you post the full workflow? Regarding the usage of `which`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918657/whats-the-use-of-which

Comment: boxplot(diamonds$carat,diamonds$cut,diamonds$depth,diamonds$table,diamonds$x,diamonds$y,diamonds$z)
boxplot(diamonds$carat,diamonds$cut,diamonds$depth,diamonds$table,diamonds$x,diamonds$y,diamonds$z)$out
outliers <-boxplot(diamonds$carat,diamonds$cut,diamonds$depth,diamonds$table,diamonds$x,diamonds$y,diamonds$z, plot = FALSE)$out
diamonds[which(diamonds$carat,diamonds$cut,diamonds$depth,diamonds$table,diamonds$x,diamonds$y,diamonds$z %in% outliers),]
Newdata <- diamonds[-which(diamonds$carat,diamonds$cut,diamonds$depth,diamonds$table,diamonds$x,diamonds$y,diamonds$z %in% outliers),]

Comment: `outliers` is a vector, you need to select only one variable when using `%in% outliers`. `Newdata <- diamonds[-which(diamonds$carat %in% outliers),]`

Comment: Rishabh, generally posting code (especially that long) in a comment is not very useful. Whenever you add some context or meaning to the question, it is typically better to edit the question directly, either replacing/modifying or adding to it.

Comment: You want to display the outliers or u want to check the outlier values?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample solution:
First we select our columns of interest

```
subset_df<diamonds[,which(names(diamonds)%in%c("carat","cut","depth","x","y","z","table"))]
```

Next, we define what defines an outlier. I've set that to any value greater than 5.

```
outliers<-subset_df[which(subset_df$z>=5),]
```

Finally, we make our boxplot.

```
boxplot(outliers)
```

Non-Outliers: I would go with `ggplot2` for reasons of preference.

```
non_outliers<-subset_df[which(subset_df$z<5),]
boxplot(non_outliers)
```

**NOTE:**

Considering the data is from `ggplot2`, you might want to consider `dplyr` and `ggplot2` for a "smoother" workflow(opinion based).

Comment: how to delete the identified outliers from the original dataset which in this case is the diamond dataset ??

Comment: Try `subset_df[-which(subset_df$z>=5),]`. You can accept an answer if it helps solve your problem.