# Imputation with column medians in R

Tags: r, matrix, apply

If I have a vector, for example

```
vec <- c(3,4,5,NA)
```

I can replace the NA with the median value of the other values in the vector with the following code:

```
vec[which(is.na(vec))] <- median(vec, na.rm = T)
```

However, if I have a matrix containing NAs, applying this same code across all columns of the matrix doesn't give me back a matrix, just returning the medians of each matrix column.

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,NA,3,5,6,7,NA,3,4,NA,2,8), ncol = 3)
apply(mat, 2, function(x) x[which(is.na(x))] <- median(x, na.rm=T) )

#[1] 3 6 4
```

How can I get the matrix back with NAs replaced by column medians? This question is similar: [Replace NA values by row means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918086/replace-na-values-by-row-means) but I can't adapt any of the solutions to my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `return(x)` as last line of the function within apply will solve it.

```
> apply(mat, 2, function(x){
    x[which(is.na(x))] <- median(x, na.rm=T)
    return(x)
  })
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6    4
[2,]    3    7    4
[3,]    3    6    2
[4,]    5    3    8
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a convenient function (`na.aggregate`) in `zoo` to replace the NA elements with the specified `FUN`.

```
library(zoo)
apply(mat, 2, FUN = function(x) na.aggregate(x, FUN = median))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    6    4
#[2,]    3    7    4
#[3,]    3    6    2
#[4,]    5    3    8
```

Or as @G.Grothendieck commented, `na.aggregate` can be directly applied on the `matrix`

```
na.aggregate(mat, FUN = median)
```

Comment: Could be shortened to:  `na.aggregate(mat, FUN = median)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck  I think you are right.  I might have tested it wrongly.