# Replacing NA values in R

Tags: r

My dataframe consists of:

```
>car_df

Grade         Speed      Age
  7             54       13
  10            NA       4
  NA            43       23
  3             NA       NA
  1             87       12
  NA            NA       NA
```

and an example of mean for each each column, ignoring NA is:

```
 > mean_col

 Grade      Speed      Age
  3.6       30.67      8.67
```

I'm trying to replace the NA values in the column **Grade and Speed** with the **mean from mean_col.**

So the new dataframe would look like:

```
Grade         Speed      Age
  7             54       13
  10            30.67    4
  3.6           43       23
  3             30.67    NA
  1             87       12
  3.6           30.67    NA
```

I tried:

```
car_df$Grade <- replace(is.na, mean_col$Grade)

car_df$Speed <- replace(is.na, mean_col$Speed)
```

But it wouldn't work. Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: ...`is.na(.), mean_col$Grade`....try this

Comment: In case that comment isn't clear, `is.na(car_df$Grade) <- mean_col$Grade`. The `replace` syntax would need to be `car_df$x <- replace(car_df$x, is.na(car_df$x), mean_col$x)`. Fill each of your columns in for `x`.

Comment: This is for row-wise, but you could certainly adapt some of the options here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6918086/210673

Answer (score 0):

With [tidyr's replace_na](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html) you can do:

```
car_df=data.frame(Grade=c(7,10,NA,3,1,NA),Speed=c(54,NA,43,NA,87,NA),Age=c(13,4,23,NA,12,NA))
library(tidyr)
replace_na(car_df,as.list(colMeans(car_df,na.rm=T)))
```